# What is the type and files in artifacts, aws buildspec yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, devops, aws-codebuild

I am a noob. What is the 'artifacts' in the buildsepc yaml file?

I read on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-build-spec-console.html,

*"**Artifacts** represents the set of build output artifacts that CodeBuild uploads to the output bucket. files represents the files to include in the build output."*
[image]

Maybe, I am not understanding it correctly. Given the settings in the screenshot above, I expect two **zipped** files(template.yml and outputtemplate.yml) to be uploaded to the output bucket, say BUCKET=MYBUCKET.

But, when I check my S3 bucket after I build and deploy it, I have 2 files named like c7e84f72729709f7a0.

Also, just to understand what's going on, I tried removing the lines: 'type: zip' and '-template.yml', and built and deployed again. I expected only 1 file since I removed line 8 and 10. But, the result was still two files sitting in my bucket. What exactly are the artifacts? And What is the type?(this I can't even find any documentations). Why is the type in most cases, if not always, zip? when in fact the uploaded file is not actually not a zip file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `c7e84f72729709f7a0` is your zip file. It will contain both yml files. Just unpack it as any other zip file. May need to add extension `.zip` if required by your unpacking software.

I don't know where the `type: zip` comes from. The [reference docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html) for the buldspec.yml do not document such a field.

And artifacts are outcomes files of your build. For example, when you are building a C++ project, it would be executable or library files  resulting from compilation of your C++ source code.

The artifices are also carried over to a next stage of your CI/CD pipeline, such as integration testing or deployment with CodeDeploy.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Marcin's answer, the `type` property of `artifacts` was deprecated in version 0.2 (the one that's being used here). You can see the changes across buildspec versions [at the bottom of this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-versions).